# DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed.Invalid file

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, automated-tests, hp-uft

I'm running Excel tests on UFT and sometimes I get the error number 20012 which is "DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed.Invalid file".

This is my way of importing the script:

```
DataTable.ImportSheet filepath,scriptname,"Action2"
```

- filepath is the path of my workbook which conatins many excel sheets (scripts)
- scriptname: the name of the script that I want to run
- Action2: contains all the call of all possible keywords that may script can contains.

Any help please, why I'm getting this error.

The problem is that this is working well for some scripts and for others not after 3 or 4 run times.

I think the problem is on Excel itself and not on the code, are there any problems when working with Excel 2016 and UFT 12 ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what are the values of your `filepath` and `scriptname` variables? As stated in @Dave's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40002722/6352151), the problem might be on what you are passing as parameters

Comment: Since you are still facing issues, as per [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126567/loop-all-the-rows-of-a-worksheet-and-copy-them-into-a-blank-sheet), I'm replying here. Please put a breakpoint in UFT on that line of code and check all of the variables, make sure they are filled correctly, make sure both file and worksheet exists (with exact same name, with same extension, `.xls` is different than `.xlsx`, which is different than `xla` and so forth) and also the "Action2" exists (just for the sake of testing). Let us know of the results

Answer (score 1):

UFT syntax for importing a worksheet is:

```
DataTable.ImportSheet FileName, vtSrcSheet, vtDstSheet
```

This means you need to pass as parameters the filename (and path) to the excel file, the name (or index) of the source sheet you want to import, and then the destination you want this sheet to be (for example "Global" or "Action1" etc)

Unless `scriptname` happens to be the exact name of the worksheet you are trying to import you will get this error.

If you want to import the whole file use `Datatable.Import` instead of `Datatable.ImportSheet`

Comment: So long as the file path is valid and points to a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file, the sheet you are importing exists and has the name you specify, and Action2 exists then yes it should be valid.  Note import will also fail if you have the workbook open when the import command is run.

Comment: Yes in my case scriptname is exact name of the worksheet I'm trying to import, I think I have to pass as parameters the FilePath and not the File Name unless how UFT will find the worksheet to import ?

Comment: I close all the Excel instances before importing the sheet, that's why I'm surprising why I got this error !!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual values you are using?

Comment: DataTable.ImportSheet "C:\scripts\script1.xls" ,"Test_1", "Action2"

Comment: Try using the index of the sheet and action instead?  Both are set to start from 1.

Comment: You said you are using Excel 2016 but your file is C:\scripts\script1.xls, so I have to ask: are you sure your file extension is correct? Excel 2016 files are **xlsx** by default, unless you changed it