# Loop all the rows of a worksheet and copy them into a blank sheet

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm facing a serious problem while importing my script into UFT for more than 2 weeks, I tried everything. As a worarround, I'm cpying the workbook and then I import the new on but this sometimes doesn't work too.
this is my code:

```
DataTable.ImportSheet workbook1,"name1","sheet1"
```

this is my workarround:

```
On error resume next
DataTable.ImportSheet workbook_path,"name1","sheet1"
MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Source & ") - " & Err.Description

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  If err.number = 20012 Then
Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")      
objExcel1.Visible = False
objExcel1.DisplayAlerts=False

Dim RelativePath
RelativePath = "C:\xyz\new_workbook.xls"
Dim objSheet1
Set objWorkbook1= objExcel1.Workbooks.Open("workbook.xls")
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If filesys.FileExists(RelativePath) Then
filesys.DeleteFile RelativePath
End If 

Set objWorkbook2=objExcel1.Workbooks.Add   
objWorkbook2.saveAs RelativePath

For each objsheet1 in objworkbook1
objworkbook2.AddSheet  objsheet1.Name
objsheet1.copy objworkbook2.sheets(1)   
Next
objWorkbook2.save
objworkbook1.close
objworkbook2.close
objExcel1.Quit
Set objSheet1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook2 = Nothing
Set objExcel1 = Nothing

On error resume next
DataTable.ImportSheet RelativePath,"name1","sheet1"
 MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Source & ") - " & Err.Description
End if 
End If
```

I want to try looping all the rows of the sheets and copying them into the new ones instead of copying them directly. Any help please ? if anyone has other solution to solve this issue, pleeeeeeease help

Comment: I have an issue and copying the sheet directly is not working for me, I need to try looping all the rows

Comment: what issue? Maybe it can be fixed.

Comment: "DataTable.importSheet operation failed. Invalid file", as a workarround, I create a copy of all the workbook and them I import the new one. This is working but not for all the sheets, I'm wasting much time on this issue without a solution, I want to try copying the wanted sheet by looping all its rows, this may works until I find a real solution for this issue

Comment: Probably the best start is to show what your code looks like.

Comment: So your main issue is that QTP/UFT DataTable operation is failing? and you need this to have a workaround?

Comment: This issue is related to [This other question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002360/datatable-importsheet-operation-failed-invalid-file), isn't it? If so, why not continue to reply on that thread until you have the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Why loop through the rows if you want them all? Just copy the sheet. IF you need the code for that, fire up the macro recorder, copy the sheet and stop the macro recorder.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DataTable.ImportSheet workbook1,"name1","sheet1"` call to `DataTable.ImportSheet workbook1,"name1","Action1"` or to `DataTable.ImportSheet workbook1,"name1","Global"`. Make sure that your path is correct for the workbook and **name1** sheet exists in your workbook

Comment: I'm already working with                                                 DataTable.ImportSheet  workbook_Path,"sheet_name","Action2"  I just changed the names for security purpose

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to import manually into DataTable? Sometimes, the special characters from the spreadsheet throw error.

If you are receiving "Invalid file error", follow the steps.

```
1. Open UFT and Activate Data Table and Perform the below action
```

Perform [image: Import Sheet]

2. Choose the appropriate sheet to be imported.
3. Check if any "Invalid File Error Dialog". If yes Goto Step 5 else GoTo Step 2
4. Go back to actual spreadsheet and **replace all of the special characters including spaces and clear all the Formatting of the cells**